# ContinousDelivery: `AssemblyInfo.cs` version information with Cake script and GitVersion

Tags: c#, msbuild, cakebuild

I'm using [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/) using [GitVersion tool](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/gitversion) ([GitHub project](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion)).

Currently, I'm only playing with my `build.cake`:

```
#tool "nuget:?package=GitVersion.CommandLine"

var target = Argument("target", "Default");

Task("Default")
  .Does(() =>
{
  Information("Hello World!");

  GitVersion(new GitVersionSettings{
    UpdateAssemblyInfo = true,
    OutputType = GitVersionOutput.BuildServer
  });

  GitVersion versionInfo = GitVersion(new GitVersionSettings{ OutputType = GitVersionOutput.Json });
  Information("Version: " + versionInfo.NuGetVersion);

  MSBuild("./CEST.sln");
});

RunTarget(target);
```

Each time I run this script, `GitVersion` changes my `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file. So, each time I perform this script, git warns me I've a file changed.

How could I avoid this?

Comment: No, there isn't a cake tag

Comment: The correct tag to use in this case would be `cakebuild`, but it looks like david.s edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but here goes...

The simplest way to work around this, would be to **only** run the initial call to GitVersion when you are running on your Continuous Integration Server.  (I am assuming that you are running a CI server, due to using this):

```
OutputType = GitVersionOutput.BuildServer
```

If this is the case, then perhaps something like this would better suit your needs:

```
Task("Default")
    .Does(() =>
{
    Information("Hello World!");

    if (!BuildSystem.IsLocalBuild) 
    {
        GitVersion(new GitVersionSettings {
            UpdateAssemblyInfo = true,
            OutputType = GitVersionOutput.BuildServer
        });
    }

    GitVersion versionInfo = GitVersion(new GitVersionSettings{ OutputType = GitVersionOutput.Json });
    Information("Version: " + versionInfo.NuGetVersion);

    MSBuild("./CEST.sln");
});
```

This way, you still have access to the asserted Semantic Version numbers when doing a local build within the `versionInfo` object which you can use throughout the rest of the build, however, the update to the AssemblyInfo.cs file doesn't occur, therefore your problem goes away.

Now, you could argue that you **want** the AssemblyInfo.cs file updated with each new Semantic Version, however, I would argue that you only **need** this when you are shipping the application, which typically only happens as the result of a CI build, rather than a local build.

You can see a more in depth example of this within the Cake.Recipe project that I have been working on:

https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Recipe/blob/develop/Cake.Recipe/Content/gitversion.cake

Answer (score 0):

And then a year later, I'm very late to the party :D

I went looking for something similar, but never really got something that matched what I was looking for - to be able to have this work for multiple projects/assemblies in a single solution, and to flexibly change each to have its own metadata/versioning.  Which led me to a custom solution, which I've repurposed as a Cake.Recipe task that looks like the below.  Relies on a second file (AssemblyTemplate.cs) in the same directory as you want the AssemblyInfo.cs file (just a c&p of the info file, typically under Project\Properties), and uses a SolutionInfo.cs file generated using GitVersion (this is currently default for Cake.Recipe but you could tweak this anywhere). It replaces lines in the template with a token for lines in the generated version.  Means you can check in the AssemblyTemplate.cs, gitignore the AssemblyInfo.cs and SolutionInfo.cs then you're done.  You can run this on a dev box, or build server, and will generate versioning details.
Please mind the cruft.

Can make the template look something like:

```
// For a static assembly version
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("TEMPLATE")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("TEMPLATE")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("TEMPLATE")]
```

Cake.Recipe Code:

```
Task("Generate-AssemblyInfo")
    .Does(() => {
        Information("Generate-AssemblyInfo started");

        // Read in solutioninfo
        var slnInfo = GetFiles(BuildParameters.SourceDirectoryPath + "/SolutionInfo.cs").FirstOrDefault();
        if(slnInfo == null) {
            Error("No solution info file could be found");
            return;
        }
        var slnData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(slnInfo.FullPath);
        //Debug(slnData);

        // Find template files
        var templateFiles = GetFiles("./**/AssemblyTemplate.cs");
        foreach(var file in templateFiles)
        {
            Information("Generating assemblyinfo from template: "+file);
            // Read AssemblyTemplate
            var templateData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file.FullPath);

            // Replace template with Solutioninfo items
            var assemblyData = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(var line in templateData)
            {
                var templateToken = "(\"TEMPLATE\")";
                if(line.Contains(templateToken)) {
                    var attr = line.Substring(0, Math.Min(line.Length, line.IndexOf(templateToken)));
                    var replLine = slnData.Where(p => p.StartsWith(attr)).FirstOrDefault();
                    Debug("Replacing: "+attr+" in template "+file+" with "+replLine);
                    assemblyData.AppendLine(replLine);
                } else {
                    assemblyData.AppendLine(line);
                }
            }

            // Save AssemblyInfo
            var assemblyDataLines = assemblyData.ToString().Split(
                new[] { System.Environment.NewLine },
                StringSplitOptions.None
            );
            var assemblyInfoPath = new FilePath(file.GetDirectory() + "/AssemblyInfo.cs");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(assemblyInfoPath.FullPath, assemblyDataLines);
        }
    });
```